# Is it possible to create an array/list of Application/Activity objects each with its own Context, each with its own LocationManager?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-location

Please note, I am VERY new to Android.

I am trying to research ways of saving battery life by trying to limit location sensing, etc... To do this, I want to "piggyback" location sensing of multiple Location Based Applications. What I want to achieve is to simulate multiple such applications, each with its own LocationListener - the LocationManager coming from the application context, I would like to try to spawn new applications as if i was instantiating objects - from a single activity.
The important thing here is so I can have a multitude of different application contexts stored in an array or list.

so, in short, a way to do something along the lines of:

```
Vector<Application> applications = new Vector<Application>();

applications.add( new Application() );
applications.add( new Application() );

// here new Application would only be an object which extends Application
```

etc... of course, Application could be an Activity or a Service... I'm just not sure how to do it, so I could then run location sensing via the LocationManager in each - separately and independently of each other.

Thanks and take care! :)

Sincerely,
Piotr.

==============================================================================

EDIT:

So the following to save battery life is redundant?:

"of the six scenarios below. For simplicity, we use the notation of
{(Maintained states), Incoming state} to denote each scenario. We
use (t, T0, D0) to denote the incoming request, where t is the time,
T0 is the requested update time interval, and D0 is the requested
distance interval. For the maintained states, we use (Gps, T1, D1)
to denote the Gps state with the ﬁnest time interval being T1 and
ﬁnest distance interval being D1. We use (Net, T2, D2) to denote
the Net state with the ﬁnest time interval being T2 and the ﬁnest
distance interval being D2."

```
• {(Gps), Gps}: The prototype checks whether the (Gps, T1, D1)
state is valid. If so, then it compares (T1, D1) to (T0, D0). If
T1 < T0 and D1 < D0, then piggybacking is enabled, and the
piggybacking time is calculated.
• {(Gps), Net}: As Net typically has coarser location information
than Gps, the operations are similar to the ({Gps},Gps) scenario,
but the comparison is between (T2, D2) and (T0, D0).
• {(Net), Net}: Similar to {(Gps), Gps} case by replacing Gps
with Net.
• {(Net), Gps}: Since Gps is typically ﬁner than Net, the request
cannot piggyback on existing Net registrations. The new registration is passed through                 immediately.
• {(Gps, Net), Gps}: Similar to {(Gps), Gps}.
• {(Gps,Net), Net}: The prototype ﬁrstly checks the Net state,
which is similar to that of {(Net), Net}. If not possible to piggyback, then it checks the     Gps     state, which is similar to {(Gps),
Net} scenario.
```

Pseudo Code:

```
(c) Sensing Piggybacking (SP)
Variables
StateGps: Gps registration state
StateNet: Net registration state
time: Requested location sensing frequency
dist: Requested location sensing distance
1 Received requestLocationUpdate(provider, time, dist,...)
2 Store information about provider, time, distance
3 Check validity of StateGps and StateNet
4 If provider == Gps
5 Compare StateGps to time and dist
6 If StateGps allows piggybacking
7 Delays the registration to enable piggybacking
8 End
9 Else // provider == Net
10 Compare StateNet to time and dist
11 If StateNet allows piggybacking
12 Delays the registration to enable piggybacking
13 Else
14 Compare StateGps to time and dist
15 If StateGps allows piggybacking
16 Delays the registration to enable piggybacking
17 End
18 End
19 End
```

If this is not redundant, then how would one go about implementing it? :)

Once again, thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to launch new applications instances on the fly and supplying them with your "cached" location data?

Comment: What i want essentially is to instantiate them from an object on the fly - one containing location sensing functionality, and then storing each instance in a list to be accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying is to essentially hijack the application lifecycle for your own purposes. This is not how it works - Android applications declare how they want to be run (mostly in `AndroidManifest.xml`), and the OS acts accordingly to that specification.

Without modifying the OS, your approach can't be realized. And that's a good thing.

Let me put it this way - as an application developer, would it make sense for you to have a possibility of implementing your solution? I.e. some other developer writes an app that changes how your application works, just like that? You may have loft goals (reducing battery life), other devs might not be so noble.

I'd advise you to read the entire [Applications Fundamentals section](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) (not just the first page), you'll gain a basic understanding of how Android works.

*Update after the link to the article was provided:* no, what I said is that the approach you described is not possible :). The authors of the paper try a different approach - they register a new `LocationProvider`. **How** they do it exactly is unclear - it depends on what they meant with the sentence "SP is hooked into the location-sensing registration function, requestLocationUpdate().". Also, they did this on a `G1` phone, which was one of the earliest Android consumer devices. What they wrote is likely obsolete by now in the context of implementation details.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! So what you're saying is that what they write about in the paper - the piggybacking - is not possible to implement without modifying the OS?

Answer (score 0):

> To do this, I want to "piggyback" location sensing of multiple Location Based Applications.

This will be done automatically by hardware and OS, for any conventional definition of "piggyback".

If 100 apps simultaenously are asking for GPS fixes, that the hardware will not spontaneously grow 100 GPS radios. There is (at most) *one* GPS radio, consuming *one* amount of power, delivering location fixes to the current apps requesting them.

> The important thing here is so I can have a multitude of different application contexts stored in an array or list.

That is not possible.

Comment: Oh okay, so the LocationManager instance is static and shared across ALL of the applications running on an android device? In other words, it is the same one accessible across the entire device and all of its applications, so each of them will get the same location with no additional power? I'm just trying to make sense of this paper in that case: http://www.deutsche-telekom-laboratories.com/~kyuhan/papers/MobiSys10Kim.pdf - the section about "piggybacking"... what's the point of it if it shares the same LocationManager across the entire device? the "multiple location based applications" part.

Comment: @Piotr: "the LocationManager instance is static and shared across ALL of the applications running on an android device?" -- the `LocationManager` is an object talking to a core OS process, which is the one actually determining the locations. "so each of them will get the same location with no additional power?" -- again, the amount of power drain is mostly determined by whether the GPS radio is powered on or not, and having several simultaneous apps does not somehow change that.

Comment: @Piotr: With respect to that paper, it is from 2010 and is referring to a 2008-vintage device. Moreover, the proposed techniques should be (and nowadays largely are) implemented in the OS layer.